# automatically set the 300x300 image as a thumbnail, Is that possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, image, thumbnails

I have an website where you can upload from front end and when you make a new post the image goes into custom field imagepost and Wordpress makes 3 more images after the original with diferent sizes and dimension and if I make to set automatically original image as thumbnail some images are bigger than 8 mb and facebook says can't download my image so I need a solution to get into thumbnail image generated by wordpress , ex: image-300.270.jpg not the original image.

Comment: www.stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: I search and found this function : update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id ); but this put my original image into thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

You can add new sizes of images with:
add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop );

You have to do this in your functions.php archive.

Comment: I don't want to add new size to image . When the post it's created original image goes into custom post and also into thumbnail for shares , but wordpress create 3 more images , image-150x135 , image-200x220, image-300x270.png , what i want it's that image-300x270 to go into thumbnail because some original images may be over 8mb and image-300x270 has 35 kb,

Comment: That's a mistake probably made on functions.php. Wordpress creates always 3 size of images(thumbnail,medium,large). Maybe you are working with a template that must be repaired. Check functions.php to see how many sizes you are creating.

Comment: No no , you are right , I want to set large image as thumbnail not uploaded image(original image)

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct all you need to do is to call the actual image for your post thumbnail with a function the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr );

According to this page you can call multiple default post thumbnail sizes like this:

```
the_post_thumbnail();                  // without parameter -> 'post-thumbnail'

the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );            // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
the_post_thumbnail( array(100, 100) );  // Other resolutions
```

More info here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: Hey, i try and doesn't work , look : http://i.imgur.com/2bqQdsK.png custom standard image and featured image it's the same , only difference it's the featured image has other dimension but same size... 9mb.